# Missing data while copying data cubes from SAP BW to Azure with OpenHub

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, data-integration, sap-bw

I need to copy data cubes from SAP BW to some Azure storage (SQL Database, Data Lake, SQL DW - anything which can connect to PowerBI).

I first tried to use a SAP via MDX connector and to copy to a SQL Database - but the tables (in preview) had missing data - ex: I had sales by month and by country, but the combination sales in Jan in UK were missing (and this data is in the cubes)

Now I tried Open Hub connection in SAP but I can see only some basic data (no master data - like name of the country only a code).

What do you advice me to do? I believe this sort of copy activity is quite common so it should be easy to solve.

Comment: Is it also an option to convert the cubes into flatten cubes (https://www.sap.com/documents/2015/08/9c62e17e-5b7c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html) and then import this in Azure?
Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Add your comment as an edit to the question

Comment: `I can see only some basic data (no master data - like name of the country only a code)` give samples what you imply under "no master data" and/or screnshots. OpenHub allows [any type of source](https://imgur.com/G7CqCq0) so your configuration seems to be wrong

Comment: The "name of the country" you were looking for is part of the "Attributes" of the dimension. Native BW connector from Azure is limited. Check out the comparison blog here: http://www.aecorsoft.com/blog/2019/1/31/use-adf-and-ssis-to-copy-data-from-sap-bw-the-comparison-of-options

Comment: @Suncatcher I mean dimensions by master data, like country, region, language. And fact data are the measures (so numbers) like sales, quantity, etc.

Comment: Thanks @AecorSoft, I also arrived at that conclusion.

Fortunately I was able to solve it like this:
1) look in SAP BW for the tables which were holding the master data (country)
2) imported them in Azure using connector SAP via Table
3) merged the data extracted via Openhub with the master data in a data flow (ADF)

Comment: So post your solution so others can make use of it

Comment: @CosmanDana Congratulations you have solved the issue. I help you post it as answer. You can accept(mark) it ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations you have solved the issue:

"Fortunately I was able to solve it like this:

1. look in SAP BW for the tables which were holding the master data
   (country)
2. imported them in Azure using connector SAP via Table
3. merged the data extracted via Openhub with the master data in a data
   flow (ADF)"

I help you post it as answer and This can be beneficial to other community members.